# Binding with Path and Source in code in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have this XAML:

```
<MenuItem Name="celsiusBtn"
          Header="{Binding Path=celsiusBtn, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" 
          IsChecked="True"
          Click="celsiusBtn_Click" />
```

I'm using this to bind string and be able to change them at runtime:

[`WPF Runtime Localization`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22967/WPF-Runtime-Localization)

Now my problem is I need to do the same binding in code, but I don't know how to specify the `Source` in the `Binding`. I know I can give the `Path` or the property name in the constructor of the class, but I'm unsure on how to access the Source property or even to define it to the `StaticResource`.

Comment: Is the Resources is static class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of `Binding` in code for `Label.Content` property, what I tested:

```
// analogue of this line: 
// {Binding Path=LabelCultureName, Source={StaticResource Resources}}

var binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("LabelCultureName");
binding.Source = (ObjectDataProvider)App.Current.FindResource("Resources");

TestLabel.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, binding);
```

In your case it will be something like this:

```
var binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("celsiusBtn");
binding.Source = (ObjectDataProvider)App.Current.FindResource("Resources");

celsiusBtn.SetBinding(MenuItem.HeaderProperty, binding);
```